# Avoiding creating new method object

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, inheritance, methods

According to the Python 2.7.12 Documentation,

> When the attribute is a user-defined method object, a new method
>   object is only created if the class from which it is being retrieved
>   is the same as, or a derived class of, the class stored in the
>   original method object; **otherwise, the original method object is
>   used as it is.**

I'm trying to understand this paragraph by writing code:

```
# Parent: The class stored in the original method object
class Parent(object):
    # func: The underlying function of original method object
    def func(self): 
        pass
    func2 = func

# Child: A derived class of Parent
class Child(Parent):
    # Parent.func: The original method object
    func = Parent.func

# AnotherClass: Another different class, neither subclasses nor subclassed
class AnotherClass(object):
    # Parent.func: The original method object
    func = Parent.func

a = Parent.func
b = Parent.func2
c = Child.func
d = AnotherClass.func

print b is a
print c is a
print d is a
```

The output is:

```
False
False
False
```

I expect it to be:

```
False
False
True
```

Comment: Try: `print Parent.func is Parent.func`.

Comment: @Robᵩ `print Parent.func is Parent.func` gives `False`, but `print a is a` gives `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you write `Parent.func`, you are getting a new unbound method object.  So `AnotherClass.func` never changes, but `Parent.func` does.  You can see this if you do something like this:

```
a = Parent.func
a2 = Parent.func
b = Parent.func2
c = Child.func
d = AnotherClass.func
d2 = AnotherClass.func
```

Then:

```
>>> a is a2
False
>>> d is d2
True
```

So your comments referring to "the original method object" are somewhat misleading.  Each part of your code that evaluates `Parent.func` is getting a different method object. (Note that the quotation you gave does not apply to `Parent.func`, because `func` as written in `Parent` is not a method object; it is a function object.  It is only when you access the attribute by writing `Parent.func` that you get a method object.)

I'm adding a bit here to clarify the quotation you gave.

I think you are misunderstanding what that quotation is saying.  This may be because the quotation is somewhat vague about the distinction between "the attribute" and the value retrieved by getting that attribute.

Let me clarify by separating two notions.  In an expression like `something.attr` I'll use "the raw value" to refer to the actual value stored in the class/object dictionary, i.e., the value of `something.__dict__['attr']`.  I'll use "the evaluated value" to refer to the actual result of evaluating `something.attr`.  The difference between the two is that the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) is activated on the raw value to get the evaluated value.

The documentation you quoted is describing a situation where the *raw* value is a method object.  This is the case in your definitions of Child and AnotherClass.  The quotation does *not* apply to `func` inside Parent, because in that case the raw value is not a method; it is a function.  In that case, the following paragraph of the documentation applies:

> When a user-defined method object is created by retrieving a user-defined function object...

In other words, the documentation you quoted ("When the attribute is a user-defined method object") applies to cases like this:

```
obj = [a method object]

class Foo(object):
    attr = obj
```

Your quoted documentation does not apply to the following case.  In this case, the attribute is "a user-defined function object":

```
func = [a function object]

class Foo(object):
    attr = func
```

In your example, there is no "original method object".  You can only get a method object *after* the class is defined.  The "original" object is a function object.  When you write `func` in the class body, you are defining a function; it is only when you *access* `Parent.func` that you get a method object.

Comment: But why does it return a new object every time?

Comment: @Rawing: See a little further down in the same documentation you quoted: "Note that the transformation from function object to (unbound or bound) method object happens each time the attribute is retrieved from the class or instance."  The fact that the object is different every time is essentially an implementation details (and in Python 3 unbound method objects no longer exist), but there is certainly no guarantee that the method object will ever be the same.

Comment: @Rawing: Method objects are short-lived and easy to allocate from a free list. Keeping them around would increase memory consumption and complicate the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what my quotation refers to.

Comment: Hmm...What do you mean by saying "Note that the quotation you gave does not apply to `Parent.func`"? I know that the function definition `def func(self):    pass` gives me a function object, rather than a method object. `Parent.func` is an attribute access, giving me a method object, so IMHO the quotation should apply to it.

Comment: And can you find "the original method object" mentioned by the quotation in my code?

Comment: @sunqingyao: There is no "original method object".  There is an original *function* object, and when you try to access it via the attribute, you get a method object.  I've edited my answer to hopefully clarify a bit more.

Comment: @sunqingyao: Also, what I mean by "the quotation does not apply" is that the procedure described in the quotation does not happen when you access `Parent.func`.  The quotation is telling you that if you define an attribute whose "raw" value is a method object, then when you access it you get a method object.  Elsewhere in the documentation it explains how when the raw value is a function object, you also get a method object.

Comment: Got it. Very nice answer.